# how to convert mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8") into PDO format in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I trying to solve the UTF8 problem. So far i manage to test out and it works in mysqli connection.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tesddddt";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["uid"]. " - Name: " . $row["username"]. " " . $row["email"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I manage to Insert and Select data with characters shown in it's language format correctly with the above coding.

However, when I try to do it in PDO , it shows 1 error when I insert data.

```
public function __construct(){
    try {       

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user_name, $this->db_pass);
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8"); // <- added here
        $this->conn=$conn;
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**I got this error**

```
Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in...
```

My php project is using PDO and hence need to get this work in PDO format. Anyone know how to settle this?

Comment: [it should go in the DSN](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You try to connect via PDO and then change the charset via mysqli, without having a mysqli connection, that is what's causing the warning.

In PDO the charset usually is being specified within the connection string, like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8");
```

Comment: the second option is not the same as mysqli_set_charset() and thus shouldn't be mentioned. especially because the OP is using PDO in emulation mode. you may read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php